Jetpack fuel show in label
I have a code to the main character and have a label detached to the camera2d which is the child of CharacterBody2d. I want to make the jetpack_fuel variable shown on the label that is also called jetpack_fuel :
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed = 200
const jump_velocity = -400
var direction = Vector2()
var jetpack_fuel = 100
var jetpacking = false
@onready var sprite_2d = $Sprite2D

var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
var animation = 'idle'

func _jetpacking(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump") and jetpack_fuel > 0:
        velocity.y = jump_velocity * 0.5 
        jetpack_fuel -= 10 * delta 
        animation = 'jetpacking' 
    else:
        velocity.y += gravity * delta 
        if not is_on_floor():
            animation = 'jumping' 

func _walking_n_running():
    direction = Input.get_axis("GoLeft", "GoRight")
    if direction != 0:
        velocity.x = direction * speed
        if speed > 200 and is_on_floor():
            animation = "running"
        if speed <= 200 and is_on_floor():
            animation = "walking"
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, 16)
        if is_on_floor():
            animation = "idle"  

func _jump(delta):
    jetpacking = true
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("Jump"):
        velocity.y = jump_velocity
        animation = 'jumping'
        jetpacking = false
    elif not is_on_floor():
        _jetpacking(delta)
func _running():
    if Input.is_action_pressed('Sprint'):
        speed = 280
    else:
        speed = 200

func _flip():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed('GoLeft'):
        sprite_2d.flip_h = true
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed('GoRight'):
        sprite_2d.flip_h = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    _jump(delta)
    _walking_n_running()
    _running()
    _flip()
    move_and_slide()
    sprite_2d.animation = animation

I have a label named jetpack_fuel as a child of Camera2d and the Camera2d is the child of CharacterBody2d. I want to make the variable jetpack_fuel shown in the label

As always, there are multiple ways to do this. For example, you could choose to complete this action in scripts attached to any of your nodes, depending on your workflow and preferences. You could even define your variable in a global singleton script, and have your various scenes access that script.
Let's do it by accessing the label in your character script. Essentially, we want to find the node by using get_node(), or $, and then set it to your var. It's basically the same process that you have done for sprite_2d.
...
var jetpack_fuel = 100
var jetpack_fuel_label = get_node('name_of_camera_node/name_of_label')

func _ready()
   jetpack_fuel_label.text = "%s" % jetpack_fuel
...

Now, the label doesn't update when jetpack_fuel updates. For this, you could do the same setting line in a _process() function, which would then set the jetpack val every single frame. This is not efficient, as it would constantly be setting the value (even when standing still), but it is easy. Another, better, way to do this would be to simply put that line in again wherever jetpack_fuel is actually changed.
